# GCLOUD: Add an abandoned instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm new to gcloud. I need to deploy an API to Instance Groups and I dont want to replace all instances. I want to abandon one instance of the instance group, deploy the API on that instance, and then add it again to the group.

I want to do this in the shell script.

To abandon instance, I use:
`gcloud compute instance-groups managed abandon-instances NAME --instances=INSTANCE,[INSTANCE,…] [--region=REGION | --zone=ZONE] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]`

Is there a way to add that instance to the group after deploy and debug an API without recreating/replacing a new instance?

Comment: I discourage your approach. Managed Instance Groups are best considered as groups of perfect clones. Attempting to tweak one instance in a group, breaks this "intent". A better alternative may be to create a new template with the desired changes and then gradually replace the Managed Instance Group based on the original template with one based on the new template.

Comment: thanks DazWilkin, I'm trying to save money for those replacements but now I think that is mandatory do the replacement of the instance.

Comment: That's correct. It should cost you no more. Ideally you would step-off the old group as you step-on the new group: assuming 3 instances, old-3|new-0 then old-2|new-1 then old-1|new-2 ... One advantage is that, if your change is problematic, you can rollback. Another is that you retain a reproducible history of changes